# How can I make an annotation like maps app has

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, annotations, mapkit

I have an app with map and a lot of annotations that are made with custom image, and my problem is that when i drag the map or zoom the annotation shows another point (lat , lon).

So I was wondering because I see this bug in other applications too, is there any way to fix it (to be as the maps annotation that always shows the right lat and lon).

This is the code I use for annotation:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }


    var reuseId = ""

    if annotation is FBAnnotationCluster {

        reuseId = "Cluster"
        var clusterView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        clusterView = FBAnnotationClusterView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId, configuration: FBAnnotationClusterViewConfiguration.default())
        return clusterView
    }else{

        reuseId = "pin"
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if  annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "locat.png")


        }
        else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation

        }

        let cpa = annotation as! FBAnnotation

        annotationView!.image = nil

        let image = UIImage(named:cpa.nameImage)


        annotationView!.image = image


        return annotationView
    }




}
```

If you have any question about what I'm asking or anything else please feel free to leave a comment.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I upload it an [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lxlzeey1kv0ipth/Untitled1.mov?dl=0) showing my problem

**EDIT2**

And here is a [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nblo3sh2tw5knw8/Untitled3.mov?dl=0) from maps that showing that their annotation is not losing its lat and lon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the `MKAnnotationView`.`centerOffset` you need to adjust this property in the `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?`

**As is defined in MKAnnotationView Documentation**

> centerOffset  Property The offset (in points) at which to display the
>   view.
>
> var centerOffset: CGPoint
>
> Discussion By default, the
>   center point of an annotation view is placed at the coordinate point
>   of the associated annotation. You can use this property to reposition
>   the annotation view as needed. This x and y offset values are measured
>   in points. Positive offset values move the annotation view down and to
>   the right, while negative values move it up and to the left.

***Something like this***

```
var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if  annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
            annotationView!.image = UIImage(named: "locat.png")
            //this is an example you must to get in account the form of your current view and what you want, I think your values are CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
            annotationView?.centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((UIImage(named: "locat.png")?.size.height)!/2))

        }
        else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation

        }
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

You are not losing the lat long but your lat long are on center of your annotation image you have to change anchorPoint.

```
annotationView?.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
```

in

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, but Reinier answered first so I chose his answer as accepted